# android app cannot receive InputStream from servlet

Tags: android, servlets

I want to use the string sent by servlet in a new Activity. The servlet is running properly, but there are many errors in the android app.

It runs when "submit" button is clicked. 
I am using Tomacatv5.5 and Eclipse IDE. Do I need to import any libraries for server or what??? I can't understand the problem.

Here is the full logcat:

> 04-29 05:05:08.517: D/(1035): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb75923d0, tid 1035

04-29 05:05:08.707: W/EGL_emulation(1035): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

04-29 05:05:08.737: D/OpenGLRenderer(1035): Enabling debug mode 0

04-29 05:05:16.157: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1035): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.

04-29 05:05:16.157: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1035):   in android.widget.EditText{b4d2f200 VFED..CL .F...... 115,173-228,203 #7f080003 app:id/editText2}

04-29 05:05:16.157: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1035):   0: sent at 327856000000, 
KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=327856, downTime=327822, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }

04-29 05:05:22.557: D/Os flush(1035): yo yo

04-29 05:05:22.717: D/dalvikvm(1035): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 206K, 9% free 2981K/3264K, paused 77ms, total 88ms

04-29 05:05:22.757: D/AndroidRuntime(1035): Shutting down VM

04-29 05:05:22.767: W/dalvikvm(1035): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a64ba8)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035): Process: com.example.mticket, PID: 1035

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at 
com.example.mticket.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:232)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

04-29 05:05:22.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

04-29 05:05:27.607: I/Process(1035): Sending signal. PID: 1035 SIG: 9

Please help, I am really stuck.

Here's my android app code:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        try
        {
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Mobticket/ServletLogin");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");
            Log.d("Os flush", "yo yo");
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {             throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "+ conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message"+br.readLine(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String output;

            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("Servlet", output);
            }

            if(output.length()>0)
            {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class);
                Bundle b=new Bundle();

                b.putString("user",userid.getText().toString() );


                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);

                conn.disconnect();
                os.close();
                br.close();
                finish();
            }





        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Error",e.getMessage());}
            conn.disconnect();
        }




});
```

Comment: plese post the full logcat for the crash

Comment: I've edited the post and added the full logcat , please help.